# Modifying controller for Devise

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I know the question has been asked previously but there is no clear answer I can see. My User has more views than just signup; signin; etc. (default devise views). e.g His Profile page, Courses he is taking, Scheduling his course. I want to create/edit a controller which will have this methods and additional views for user. How do I achieve it?

Comment: What have you tried? FWIW, I just have my 'regular' `users_controller` with all my custom actions & views, and let Devise take care of the rest.

Comment: i just created profile_controller and planning to have custion actions in it. I'm not sure what it's superclass should be.

Comment: Its superclass should be the regular `ApplicationController`. It's what I'm currently doing. You will then need something like `before_filter authenticate_user!, only: [:private_action]` to keep some pages private.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite trick for this is to namespace the devise routes to not conflict with my users profile pages and such. `devise_for` takes a `path_prefix` option, so in your `config/routes.rb` you can:

`devise_for :users, :path_refix => 'd'`

and all your devise routes will be `/d/users/new`, leaving `/users` free again.

if that doesn't work for you, you can replace the default devise controller responsible for creating and editing views by subclassing `Devise::RegistrationsController` and add your routes to it. You can follow the directions [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile) for pretty good directions